# Didnot override hashCode() and equals() methods.But could find my stuff

Tags: java

According to the SCJP book,if we donot override the hashCode() and equals() method in the class being used as part of key our code should run and compile but we will not find out stuff.

Did not override hashCode() and equals() method in the class that I used a part of key,yet I could get the value retrieved.

Please find the code below:

Case 1:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Dog1{


    public Dog1(){}
    public Dog1(String n) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        name=n;
    }
    String name;
}

public class MapGen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Object,Object> m = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        Dog1 d1=new Dog1("Clover");
        //Dog1 d2 =new Dog1("Clover");
        m.put(d1, "XYZ");
        System.out.println(""+m.get(d1));
        System.out.println(""+m.size());


    }

}
```

Output:

XYZ

1

While in the following case I could see that it was unable retrieve the value.
Case 2:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Dog1{


    public Dog1(){}
    public Dog1(String n) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        name=n;
    }
    String name;
}

public class MapGen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Object,Object> m = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        Dog1 d1=new Dog1("Clover");
        //Dog1 d2 =new Dog1("Clover");
        m.put(new Dog1(), "XYZ");
        System.out.println(""+m.get(new Dog1()));
        System.out.println(""+m.size());


    }

}
```

Output:

null

1

Can anyone explain me the difference between case 1 and case 2??

Comment: Of course it wasn't, in the second case you have two different objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case 1 you are searching for the same `Dog1` instance that you inserted, which means that the `hashCode()`  implementation from `Object` works just fine (in fact, any sane implementation would work, since you are using the exact same object).

In the second case you are using two different instances when inserting and retrieving, which doesn't work. The `Object#hashCode()` method is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, which means that two instances will pretty much always have different hash codes.

Answer (score 0):

In both way Dog object doesnt override equals and hashcode.

**Approach 1**

The same Dog reference is used to put and load. So If hashcode is not overridden then object memory location is used. Since both the reference is same. So Same memory location is used . Then it works fine.

**Approach 2** 
In this approach two different reference used. So Both the memory locations are different. Then map didnt find the value of second memory location.